# javascript update depth dictionary (include array)

Tags: javascript

Like Python, I want to update by specifying only specific values.
Like this.
[Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth)

```
ori={
   "item": {
        "_props": {
            "Width": 1,
            "Grids": [
                {
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
upt={
    "item": {
        "_props": {
            "Width": 2,
            "Prefab": {
                "path": "assets"
            }
        }
    }
}
result={
    "item": {
        "_props": {
            "Width": 2,
            "Grids": [
                {
                }
            ],
            "Prefab": {
                "path": "assets"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

not this

[Add a value to an object with its key depth based on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955471/add-a-value-to-an-object-with-its-key-depth-based-on-an-array)

[JavaScript Updating a dictionary from array of values using array of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763649/javascript-updating-a-dictionary-from-array-of-values-using-array-of-keys)

result={...ori, ...upt}

Object.assign(copy, dict);

I think I could apply this, but I'm not sure.

[Javascript how to get an array depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668494/javascript-how-to-get-an-array-depth)